# K8 - round-robin load balancing between two services using nginx ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have 2 services in my cluster exposed as NodePort, and I have one Nginx Ingress Controller that routes the request to each of them depending on the request URL.

Here is my ingress definition file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: ServiceA
          servicePort: 80
        path: /serviceA/(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: ServiceB
          servicePort: 80
        path: /serviceB/(.*)
```

[image]

I am wondering what needs to be done in order to have another `backend` entry in this definition that sends 50% of requests to Service A and 50% of requests to Service B?

Comment: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#canary

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for, can you post it as an answer, or mark the question as duplicate if you feel it's a duplicate?

Comment: I don't have time to write a decent answer at the moment :-) Not sure there are duplicates, I just was familiar with the feature, so provided a link directly to it.

Comment: thank you, that link did the job. I will wait a little longer to see if someone else post it ,otherwise I will post an answer by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: canary
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-weight: "50"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: ServiceA
          servicePort: 80
        path: /serviceA/(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: ServiceB
          servicePort: 80
        path: /serviceB/(.*)
```